# JBoss logging - logging dependency projects

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, jboss5.x

We use JBoss 5.1 to deploy all of our services. But we have run into this problem.

Lets say we have 2 projects 'A' and 'B'. Both 'A' and 'B' has its own separate log file to log stuff into 'A.log' and 'B.log'. Both of these projects use a common dependency 'C'. Now, if project 'A' calls 'C' and there is a logger statement in 'C', it needs to be logged to 'A.log' as 'C' was called from 'A'.
Similarly, if Project 'B' calls 'C', the logger statement in 'C' should be logged to 'B.log'.

How do we configure JBoss and log4j to achieve this logging?

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should utilize TCLFilter/TCLMCFilter in your log4j appenders for "A" and "B" to separate out your application logs for the shared classes. Read more about it on this [wiki - SeparatingApplicationLogs](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SeparatingApplicationLogs)

For example:

```
<appender name="LogA" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"></errorHandler>
      <param name="Append" value="false"/>
      <param name="File" value="some_directory/log/a.log"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
      <filter class="org.jboss.logging.filter.TCLMCFilter">
         <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
         <param name="DeployURL" value="a.ear"/>
      </filter>    
</appender>
```

Note that for .war files the file name changes to "a-exp.war" so if you are using a war then you will need change "DeployURL" accordingly.

Comment: thanks CoolBeans..Does the new appender needs to be added for individual project's log4j configuration file or do we need to add that in JBoss's log4j configuration file.

Comment: You are welcome. It could go under jboss-log4j.xml or your own application log4j.xml. See the section `Separating Application Logs - without the monolithic jboss-log4j.xml file` on this [wiki](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SeparatingApplicationLogs) for further discussion.